# What referential should I use? Ping pong and water cup

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, conservation-laws

I'm trying to modelise the ping pong and water cup experiment.
They were already questions on stackexchange about this:

[Why does a ping pong ball bounce higher when it is dropped together with a cup of water?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/562305/)

but I would try an approach with Archimede Force and superficial tension.

[image: Image of the experiment]

I want to apply Newton's law on the ping pong ball, but the water and the cup are moving too and I don't know how it works in that case or how to modelise it...
What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

Since the experiment can replace the water by sand or by a poorly bouncing heavier ball I think the approach with Archimedes  law does not work better than the explanations in the other link.

Comment: [https://comptes-rendus.academie-sciences.fr/mecanique/item/10.5802/crmeca.46.pdf]

[https://emergent-scientist.edp-open.org/articles/emsci/full_html/2022/01/emsci210004/emsci210004.html]

I found this articles that use archimedes law to explain this phenomen that is why...

Comment: Your link does not work for me, but if the article works with archimedes why do you ask?